# Looping variables or array

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I am creating some charts using **chart.js** with the context looking like this:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2');
var ctx3 = document.getElementById('myChart3');
var ctx4 = document.getElementById('myChart4');
var ctx5 = document.getElementById('myChart5');
var ctx6 = document.getElementById('myChart6');
```

is there a way I can write some form of loop instead of manually writing every single of them?

Comment: If you add a class to all of them, you can just do `var ctxArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.chart'));` The first one will be accessible with `ctxArray[0]`, the second one with `ctxArray[1]`, etc. and you can loop over them easily

Comment: `Element.getElementsByTagName()` => method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.  Then you can use a for loop on the array.

Comment: What are the elements these ids represent?

Comment: Could you possibly share the representative html? Your question seems to be about efficient selectors, there may be an easier way to select the elements if we can see your html.

Answer (score 1):

You could compress the document.getElementById function which is a peeve for me too

```js
const gEBID = document.getElementById;
var ctx = gEBID('myChart');
var ctx2 = gEBID('myChart2');
var ctx3 = gEBID('myChart3');
var ctx4 = gEBID('myChart4');
var ctx5 = gEBID('myChart5');
var ctx6 = gEBID('myChart6');
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* store each id selector in an array before looping over the array and making a selection to operate on...

```js
const selectors = [
 '#myChart', '#myChart2', '#myChart3', '#myChart4', '#myChart5', '#myChart6' 
]

selectors.forEach(selector => {
  const chart = document.querySelector(selector)
  console.log(chart)
  // do something
})
```

```html
<div id="myChart"></div>
<div id="myChart2"></div>
<div id="myChart3"></div>
<div id="myChart4"></div>
<div id="myChart5"></div>
<div id="myChart6"></div>
```

However, this is what css classes and `querySelectorAll` do very efficiently.

```js
const myCharts = document.querySelectorAll('.chart')

myCharts.forEach(chart => {
  console.log(chart)
  // do something
})
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="myChart"></div>
<div class="chart" id="myChart2"></div>
<div class="chart" id="myChart3"></div>
<div class="chart" id="myChart4"></div>
<div class="chart" id="myChart5"></div>
<div class="chart" id="myChart6"></div>
```